# Socket Programming - CipherStream

Tags: java, sockets, encryption

I am doing File transfer (Socket - Java) program where I am sending encryped version of file to client. The Client will decrypt it and store in its drive.

I am using CipherOutputStream anf CipherIputStream for Encryption and decryption. My problem is While encryption I need to close the CipherOutputStream else the file is not receiving at the client. I need to recieve acknowledgment from client after sending the file, since I am close the  CipherOutputStream  in the server, it is not receiving the message from client. Its throwing Socket closed exception.

Is there another way to send a file in encrypted format to client so that the client will decrypt it and store it in its repository.??

Please need some advise.

Comment: Before sending the content of the file, you could send its length (the number of bytes to read afterwards). The client will receive the length and will try to read bytes of this amount.

Comment: Note that symmetric encryption requires both parties to have the same key. This is a hard problem to solve unless you have physical control over both clients. Maybe look at asymmetric encryption? Additional benefit is that it is dead-easy to set up an SSLSocket in java.

Answer (score 0):

Once a stream is closed, you cannot send back data to acknowledge the successful receiving of the file.

As written in my comment, you can first send the length of the file to the client so the client will know how many bytes it has to read. Once the client read this amount of data, the client can send back the acknowledge because the stream is not closed. Once the server received the acknowledgement, it can close the stream or initiate another transfer.

Comment: But I need to send the encrypted file before receiving the acknowledgement. Client is not receiving the file if the CipherOutputStream is closed.

Comment: @user3407267 Yes, but you don't need to close the stream. Don't close the stream.

Comment: Its not working unless I close the Stream :( Thats is the problem

Comment: @user3407267 And why doesn't it work unless you close the stream? Did you do what I suggested?

Comment: The problem is I need to send the whole file. Based on the information from the file, client will send some other info as acknowledgement.

Comment: @user3407267 I'm failing to see your problem. 1. Server sends the file length (e.g. 1234 bytes). Then sends 1234 bytes (the content of the file). 2. Client reads the length: 1234, so the client will read further 1234 bytes (the content of the file). 3. Once the client read up to 1234 bytes, the client has the whole file so the client sends back the acknowledge (can be anything you want). 4. The server receives the acknowledge, so the connection (steams) can be closed.